# Multipart Upload to Spring Rest using angular factory service and $resource

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-boot, multipart

I'm using AngularJS to communicate with a RESTful web service (running with spring boot), using $resource. I'm trying to upload some files and send form fields within a same multipart post request but i am getting the following error:

> "Unsupported Media Type"  exception:
>   "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException"  message:
>   "Content type 'application/xml' not supported"  path: "/study/upload" 
>   status: 415

here is my view form :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="submit()">
  <table>
    <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" ng-model="form.file"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="form.name"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload"  /></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

here is the view controller:

```
$scope.submit=function(){
    GalleryService.upload({file: $scope.form.file, name: $scope.form.name}, function(data) {
         console.log("Success ... " + status);
    }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
    });
}
```

gallery.service :

```
(function() {
```

'use strict';

angular
    .module('ekellsApp')
    .factory('GalleryService', GalleryService);

function GalleryService($resource, restApi) {

```
return $resource(restApi.url + '/study/:action', {},{
  save: {method: 'POST', params: {action: 'save'}},
  getAll: {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'getAll'},isArray:true},
  upload: {method: 'POST', params: {action: 'upload'}, transformRequest: angular.identity,headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }}


});
```

}

})();

and here is the REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                               @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (name.contains("/")) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Folder separators not allowed");
        return "redirect:upload";
    }
    if (name.contains("/")) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Relative pathnames not allowed");
        return "redirect:upload";
    }

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("user/bouhuila/" + name)));
            FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stream);
            stream.close();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty");
    }

    return "redirect:upload";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see what

```
 GalleryService.upload
```

is doing, but it looks like you are not really sending the form to the server, but only some fields. In this case

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

would not be used, that could explain the error you are getting.

Have a look in the developer tools in your browser, which request is actually sent to your server and which content type it is using..